# How to declare a IntPtr?

Tags: c#, intptr

I have a Window handle Picker and it says my handle is 0094167C.
When I declare the variable in c# the letter in this code gives an error.
How to declare?

public const IntPtr WinHandle = 0094167C;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know that the handle will typically change with each application and/or system start? This means your constant is subject to failure anyway.

If, however, you really want to assign a constant other than zero to an `IntPtr` (which would be `IntPtr.Zero`), the documentation states that there are constructors that take `Int32`, `Int64` or `Void*` as parameter.

Comment: Now I didn't know that handles changes. I will make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As OregonGhost points out you probably don't want to do that for a windows handle. However, for a IntPtr in general, what you can do is this static readonly fields:

```
static readonly IntPtr TenK = new IntPtr(1024 * 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to AgnosticOracle's answer.

In addition to constant-like static-readonly IntPtr/UIntPtr variables, you can use `nint` and `nuint` which are backed by IntPtr and UIntPtr, respectively.

These types can have integer and unsigned integer values assigned to them and can also be defined as constants.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#native-sized-integers